# Getting issue while setting up Sitecore Habitat 9.0 Update 2

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, habitat

I'm following this article( [SC9 Install](https://medium.com/@sivalingaamorthy/configure-sitecore-habitat-with-sitecore-9-0-update-2-in-30-minutes-ba9237a33522) )  to set up Habitat with SC9.0.2 but getting below errors at InstallWDP:WebDeploy step:

[image]

I have installed all required software via Web platform installer but still getting same error. Any idea?

Used Web Platform Installer to install:

1. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework
2. SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
3. SQL Server System CLR Types 11.0

Even I have installed ScriptDom but `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll` is missing at `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120` location. Do I need to download manually this dll?

**Current Env:**

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- SQL 2014
- IIS 10
- SolR6.6.2 is running

Comment: Can you please go with log file there you can find more detail about error.

Comment: `PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-CommandTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)"` This is the message I'm getting in logs. message in logs almost same as in screenshot

Also not sure why webdeploy.exe is triggered

Comment: I'm thinking to remove "InstallWDP" step in xconnect-xp0.json file

Comment: Can you please check again in web platform installer that web deploy is showing installed or not.

Comment: Yes DACFs June 2014 ,SQL 2012 SP1 Transact-SQL ScriptDom  , CLR Types for SQL 2012 showing installed

Answer (score 1):

Habitat is an XP install. For 9.0.2 you need to install SQL 2016 SP1 to run Habitat.

Per Sitecore's compatibility chart, 9.0 can only use SQL 2014 SP2 in CMS only mode. For 9.0 with XP you need 2016 SP1.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

#### Update

Lets install it via SQL Powershell.

1. Install SQL PowerShell by running `Import-Module -Name SqlServer` in PowerShell with admin privileges.
2. Open the folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer` and then open the version that is in that folder.

NOTE: The next steps believes you have the gacutil.exe in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll` in the folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18068\`

3. Run this command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18068\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"`

I got this idea from https://craftmandev.com/2018/02/28/common-problems-for-installation-sitecore-9-on-the-first-time/

Comment: I installed SQL 2017 Developer edition but no luck. While searching on google I found this can be fixed by executing below 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"`
On my machine even  \DAC\130 folder doesn't exist. I do have \DAC\120 only which doesn't contains `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll`
`https://forums.iis.net/t/1235672.aspx?Web+Deploy+ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER`

Comment: I got below while executing SELECT @@VERSION 
`Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)`

Comment: I installed `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55114` but still can't get `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll`

Comment: Do you have either of these folders? `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies` or  `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\`

Comment: Yes I found `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies` folder and moved dll successfully to GAC. Executed `install-xp0.ps1` but getting same error 
Can I skip `InstallWDP` step from `xconnect-xp0.json` file

Comment: Please reboot and try it again.

Comment: Yes I rebooted before executing `install-xp0.ps1` . I found below in logs `PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-CommandTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)"`

Comment: Exact same error in console?

Comment: yes it's same error

Comment: If there is any other article to install Sitecore Habitat then let me know I'll follow that one

Answer (score 0):

Run command to manually register ScriptDom:

```bsh
.\GacMe -filePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"
```

Comment: Yes I made progress after this change and getting this error now even I replaced default password in `xconnect-xp0.json` and `sitecore-xp0.json` files

`Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE
More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "9" and "12". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
"CREATE USER [Sql@123+] WITH PASSWORD = 'Sql@123+"
 Password validation failed.`

Comment: Check password policy in MSSQL manager.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I did now I'm getting this error even with strong password
`Error: Password validation failed. The password does not meet Windows policy requirements because it is not complex enough.
Error count: 1.
Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE
More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "9" and "12". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
"CREATE USER [SqlPass@1234$] WITH PASSWORD = 'Sql"
 Password validation failed.`